# Why does closing socket used in a SslStream result in TCP RST instead of FIN

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, .net-6.0

I have noticed that when using an SslStream, when I close the socket I get a TCP RST packet instead of a TCP FIN packet like I would if I closed the socket without the SslStream wrapping it.

For example

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(IPAddres.Loopback, 1234);
socket.Send(new byte[] {0xc3, 0x45});
socket.Shutdown(Shutdown.Both);
```

Results in the remote getting a TCP FIN packet, whereas this

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(IPAddres.Loopback, 1234);
var ns = new NetworkStream(socket, false); // owns socket = false
var ssl = new SslStream(ns, true); // leaveInnerStreamOpen = true
ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("foobar.com");
ssl.Write(new byte[] {0xc3, 0x45});
socket.Shutdown(Shutdown.Both);
```

The remote receive a TCP RST packet. I would have expected a TCP FIN packet here just as if I had not used the SslStream at all. I have specified that the NetworkStream does not own the socket. I have told the SslStream to not close the inner stream.

I am using wireshark so I know for sure what packets are coming through.

**UPDATE 1:** If I use socket.Shutdown(Shutdown.Send) then I get a TCP FIN packet. But I can use socket.Shutdown(Shutdown.Both) when using a normal socket to get a TCP FIN packet.

**UPDATE 2:** I noticed that if I swapped my AuthAsServer and AuthAsClient around but did everything else the same, then I get the desired TCP FIN packet.

So I guess the question is why does AuthenticateAsClient produce TCP RST when closing the socket.

Comment: You probably need to close the SSL steam correctly before you close the TCP/IP socket.

Comment: Did you try to call `SslStream.ShutdownAsync` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.shutdownasync?view=net-7.0 before calling `Socket.Shutdown`?

Comment: @LexLi I will give that a try. Doesn't make sense to me how the socket knows about the SslStream though because you pass the Socket into the SslStream and not the other way around.